# How I findAll with inner join

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tables in my database, `REFD00` is Users, `REFD01` is Reservations and `REFD02` is the join table, for one reservation have N guests(Users). I need to select all reservations and get too all guests.

Tables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH3MR.png)

Reservations Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REFD01")
public class Reserva implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="R1$COD", updatable=false)
private long codigo;

@Column(name="R1DATA")
private String data;

@Column(name="R1DESC")
private String descricao;

@Column(name="R1HORA")
private String hora;

@Column(name="R1USER")
private String criador;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Utilizador
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="REFD02"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="R2$RES")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="R2$USR")
            }
        )
private List<Utilizador> refd00s;
```

Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REFD00")
public class Utilizador implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="R0$COD", updatable=false)
private long codigo;

@Column(name="R0MAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name="R0NOME")
private String nome;

@Column(name="R0PASS")
private String password;

@Column(name="R0ROLE")
private String role;

@Column(name="R0USER")
private String username;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Reserva
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="refd00s")
private List<Reserva> refd01s;
```

Method of get all reservations:

```
List<Reserva> entitys = getRepositories().getReservaRepository().findAll();
```

It's the result:

```
"codigo": 1,
"data": "2017-05-11",
"hora": "16:00",
"criador": "xpto",
"descricao": "Game",
"refd01s": null
```

Comment: Read the hibernate documentation about JPQL and fetch joins. And please, please, give meaningful names to your tables, columns, fields and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with with an `left outer join fetch`, then you can add the `@EntityGraph` configuration to that interface method:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "refd00s" }, type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
public List<Reserva> findAllWithGuests();
```

If you have use the `inner join fetch`, then you would have to either add the eager fetching configuration param in your entity (you have to be careful with this):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="REFD02"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="R2$RES")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="R2$USR")
            }
        )
private List<Utilizador> refd00s;
```

or use an explicit `@Query` definition:

```
@Query("select r from Reserva r inner join fetch r.refd00s")
public List<Reserva> findAllWithGuests();
```